# How do I make the user unable to go back to the signup/login page without logging out?

Tags: php, html

I am creating a website and the index page is a login/signup page, and i need it to be impossible for the user to go back to that page unless they log out. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put something like this at the top of the login/signup page:

```
if($_SESSION['loggedin']) {
     header('Location: loggedinpage.php');
     die();
}
```